# In how many ways you can pick 4 different items from 7 different items

Tags: combinatorics

Basically, my task is to calculate how many undersets(⊆, dont know the english term)? have odd numbers in them from set={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. For example {1}, {1,5,6}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} should be counted in.
I thought I can calculate how many containing odd number with 1 element, 2 elements  so on. I calculated (A lower number 4 upper number 1)=4, so 4 with 1 element, then (A lower number 4 upper number 1)*6=24, so 24 with 2 elements, but I tried looking at all the cases and i got 18 (12 13 14 15 16 17)(32 34 35 36 37) (52 54 56 57) (72 74 76). What's wrong?

Comment: Try subtracting all the subsets with only even elements from the total number of subsets.  This might be easier.  The total number of subsets of a list $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\}$ is $2^n-1$ if we don't count the empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of subsets are $2^7$

The number of subsets made totally out of even integers are $2^3$ therefore the number of subsets with some odd integers is $2^7-2^3=120$